# Are cross-party ability boosts active when using forms?

Tags: kingdom-hearts-2.5-remix

In Kingdom Hearts 2: Final Mix, I am currently farming materials to create Defense Boosts, primarily the [Twilight Crystal](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Twilight). This wouldn't be too difficult, if this item wasn't a 12% drop from a monster where only 5 or 6 spawn in the [Cave of Remembrance](http://kingdomhearts.wikia.com/wiki/Cavern_of_Remembrance).

There is the ability [Lucky Lucky](http://kingdomhearts.neoseeker.com/wiki/Lucky_Lucky) that increase drop rate of items, and it further boosts the rate when it is equipped across the entire party.

> Increases the Drop rate of items. The drop rate can be further increased if more characters are equipped with this ability.

The thing about that, however, is the party member needs to be active in order for the ability to be in use. When grinding the monsters that drop Twilight Crystals, the item seemed to drop more when all three party members were active rather than using a form that requires both party members.

So are the cross-party abilities boosts active when using a form that requires both party members, or seeing how they are currently not in the field, it negates the boost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some digging through multiple other guides and wikis, the cross-party abilities do become negated when using any forms that require a party member - the case is for summons as well.

[Lucky Strike/Lucky Lucky](https://www.khwiki.com/Lucky_Strike)

> In Kingdom Hearts II, Lucky Lucky is a support ability that costs 5 AP to equip. The drop rate is increased by a factor of 1 + 0.3n, where n represents the number of Lucky Lucky abilities **equipped by the active party**. Equipping all seven available copies of the ability, including those attached to equipment, results in enemies' base drop rates being multiplied by 3.1. In Kingdom Hearts II Final Mix, the factor is 1 + 0.5n and the maximum number that can be equipped is fifteen, resulting in a maximum drop rate multiplication of 8.5. The additional Lucky Lucky available in Limit Form can further raise the drop rate factor to 9.

According to [this](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/915410-kingdom-hearts-ii/55481587) Gamefaqs post, using a form or summon lowers your active party

> You only get party abilities from people who are in your active party. Driving and Summoning remove them from your active party.